# How to stop count after Position.x on node is past position.x on another node

Tags: ios, if-statement, sprite-kit, void

At the moment once my object has gone past a node, the highscore continuously counts up.
I only wish for it to count up by 1 once its past.

```
-(void)increment
{
    self.number ++;
    self.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.number];
    NSLog (@"%i", self.number);
} 


-(void)handlePoints
{
    [world enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"obstacle" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if (node.position.x < hero.position.x) {
            PMPointsLabel *pointsLabel = (PMPointsLabel *)[self childNodeWithName:@"pointsLabel"];
            [pointsLabel increment];
        }
    }];

}
```

I only want it to count up by a single number, how can I change this? It will currently keep counting for every pixel it travels.

Comment: Use a BOOL variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, as it isn't clear if your goal is to only add the point once on the `enumerateChildNodesWithName` or only increment it once it passes it completely.

To do the former

```
-(void)handlePoints
{
    [world enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"obstacle" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if (node.position.x < hero.position.x) {
            PMPointsLabel *pointsLabel = (PMPointsLabel *)[self childNodeWithName:@"pointsLabel"];
            [pointsLabel increment];

            *stop = YES; // To be extra safe you can always test for stop being non-nil, but it should always be non-nil
        }
    }];
}
```

Setting `*stop = YES` will stop the enumeration.

If you want to stop it "forever" or until some other condition, you'll need to store additional state in the class to prevent it. You would need logic based on the condition either inside `handlePoints` or in the calling method of `handlePoints` to prevent either enumeration (in the case of it being in `handlePoints` or calling `handlePoints` if it is the calling method.

Comment: This didn't work I'm afriad, I'm  just trying to make increment stop counting up once it has past the "obstacle" node.

Comment: You actually need to put up more code and be more specific. For example, who/what conditions is `handlePoints` called? Have you also verified that the code at the very least stops properly? I'm guessing your problem is `handlePoints` is being called over and over and hence it still increments. The code above solves one problem: stopping the increment for that enumeration. Note that I explained all of this above in my answer.